# objective c check if Bluetooth Availability Changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

The question is simple: Is there any way to get noticed when the users enables or disables bluetooth on a iOS device?

I searched the internet but just found some private API´s.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bluetooth Low Energy's (BTLE) interface. You will get updates whenever an user disables/enables Bluetooth in settings. Check the [CBCentralManagerDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/translated_content/CBCentralManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManagerDidUpdateState%3a). And of course you can also check the [state](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBCentralManager/state)